# Refresh image after its been replacedWith image using jQuery PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, replacewith

I am using simpleImage, a php image manipulation library.. I am trying to rotate the image externally using ajax and replaceWith. It replaces the image and everything but it wont refresh when rotated..

index.php -

```
//Submit Form
function subForm() {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $('#target').val();
console.log(name);
$.post("rotate.php", {name: name},
function(data) {
$("#preview").replaceWith( '<img id="replace" src="'+data+'"/>' );
});
}



<img src="'.$target.'" id="preview"/>

<form method="post" action='' id="rotateForm" data-ajax="false">
<input type="submit" id="rotate"  onclick="subForm();" value="rotate">
</form>
```

** UPDATED**

rotate.php -

```
$time = time();
$newImg = $_POST['name'];
$img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($newImg);
$img->rotate(90)->best_fit(500, 500)->save();
echo $newImg.'?'.$time;
```

The image rotates but doesn't update on the page with out the page being reloaded.. Am I using the wrong approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images do usually get cached by the browser.

**The problem:**

1. you show some image with a specific `src`  like `someimage.jpg`
2. You rotate that image and provide it with the same `src` `someimage.jpg`
3. the browser will load the **old one** from the **cache**!

To prevent that you could simply request a brand new one using a timestamp like

```
someimage.jpg?t=1476400456961
```

and the browser will load a clean `someimage.jpg` from the server.

---

A JS solution is:

```js
function subForm() {

  event.preventDefault();

  var name = $('#target').val();
  console.log(name);

  $.post("rotate.php", {name: name}, function(data) {
    var tStamp = +new Date(); // Generate always a new timestamp milliseconds value
    $("#preview").replaceWith( '<img id="replace" src="'+ data+"?t="+ tStamp  +'"/>' );
  });
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, I applied a timestamp but it only rotates once.. I will update the question with my changes..

Comment: @RyanD That's cause you need to always update your milliseconds timestamp with a new one! Or simply use an index `var i=0;` and on every form submit your increment that value  `someimage.jpg?t=2` ... `3, 4` etc. But I have more faith in timestamp cause for that user will always be unique.

Comment: Ya I added the timestamp in the rotate.php, wouldnt that produce a new time whenever my form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, it should (you can always use the network inspector or inspect element), but you can always generate that timestamp using JS :) See example above

Answer (score 1):

You have rewrite the src attribute of your  tag so that the image loads again.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify 'rewrite'? change the path or something to make it different?

Comment: $("#preview").attr("src","Here you put a link to your php script");